# Calculating similarity based vector with different weights

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I'm working on comparing a specific vector to a set of other vectors to determine their similarity. For this, I've been using cosine similarity. However, in my problem, not all elements (or entries) in the vectors have equal importance. I need a way to incorporate different weights for different entries in the vectors during the similarity calculation.

Could you recommend any algorithms or techniques that allow for this kind of weighted similarity calculation?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Vector proposed
propuesto = np.array([20, 85, 10, 10])

# Vector set
vector_b1 = np.array([31, 83, 22, 88.5])
vector_b2 = np.array([25.4, 114.07, 18.2, 346.68])
vector_b3 = np.array([26.9, 85, 20.9, 123.87])
vector_b4 = np.array([25.7, 87.6, 20.96, 458.8])
vector_b5 = np.array([28.6, 71.4, 28.9, 690.5])
vector_b6 = np.array([30.2, 148.9, 26.33, 317.58])
vector_b7 = np.array([25.1, 87.8, 0, 0])
vector_b8 = np.array([32.4, 158.9, 23.33, 160.14])
vector_b9 = np.array([23, 89.4, 17.99, 561])
vector_b10 = np.array([16.64, 36.7, 27.8, 526])
vector_b11 = np.array([40, 85, 10, 10])

# Vectors in matrix
matriz_b = np.array([vector_b1, vector_b2, vector_b3, vector_b4, vector_b5, vector_b6, vector_b7, vector_b8, vector_b9, vector_b10, vector_b11])

# Normalize vector
vector_a_norm = propuesto / np.linalg.norm(propuesto)

# Normalize matrix
matriz_b_norm = matriz_b / np.linalg.norm(matriz_b, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# Cosine similarity
similitudes = cosine_similarity([vector_a_norm], matriz_b_norm)

# Similarities
for i, similitud in enumerate(similitudes[0]):
    print(f"Similitud con Vector B{i + 1}: {similitud:.4f}")
```

Comment: [Sk-learn's cosine similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) already normalizes the vectors. You don't need to normalize it again

Comment: Could you explain how the entrances (I'm guess vectors) weighting scheme works?

Comment: You could try weighted cosine similarity by either manually creating a weight vector or using scipy's scipy.spatial.distance.cosine implementation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html